# Remove everything after multiple symbols within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2
A    Name=canis_lupus3099 HHYUIO jj6§è7
B    Name=bomba009 JJIJJ;HHJKN
C    Name=Test_test788_eheh;NHHhh
D    Name=UYEYEHJ0909EEHH:HEEH Jk G
```

How can I use regex in order to only keep within COL2 the Name=something part and remove everything  after a space of any symbolic point (eg ; or :)

I should then get:

```
COL1 COL2
A    Name=canis_lupus3099
B    Name=bomba009
C    Name=Test_test788_eheh
D    Name=UYEYEHJ0909EEHH
```

I touth to use something like `tab['COL2'].str.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].str.extract(r'^(Name=(?:[^\s;:])+)')
```

Alternative:

```
# everything until the first space or ; or :
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].str.extract(r'^(.*?)(?=[\s;:])')
```

output:

```
  COL1                    COL2
0    A    Name=canis_lupus3099
1    B           Name=bomba009
2    C  Name=Test_test788_eheh
3    D    Name=UYEYEHJ0909EEHH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try split:

```
df[['COL2','COL3']] = df['COL2'].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
```

after that you can delete COL3

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(df, col, symbol):
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(symbol, '')
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

A way out is to use positive look behind to extract all characters after the start.

```
df['COL2'].str.strip().str.extract('((?<=^)Name=\w+)')
```